# “.Files.Get” to import a json into a config map not working

Tags: kubernetes-helm, configmap

this is my directory structure:

```
+xyz:
     + custom-dashboard
        - abc.json
     +templates
        + grafana
            +abc.yaml
```

abc.yaml is my configmap. I have tried many different attempts

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: abc-configmap
data:
  abc.json: |-
    {{- range $mypath, $mybytes := .Files.Glob "custom-dashboards/serilog.json" }}
      {{ $mypath }}
    {{- end }}
#    {{ .Files.Get "custom-dashboards/abc.json" | indent 4}}
#  {{- $.Files.Get "custom-dashboards/abc.json" | indent 6 -}}
#  {{- (.Files.Glob "custom-dashboards/abc.json").AsConfig | indent 6 -}}
```

and many others. nothing actually loads the contents of the file for

```
k get configmap serilog-configmap -o yaml
```

It just looks like:

```
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","data":{"serilog.json":"{{- range $mypath, $mybytes := .Files.Glob \"custom-dashboards/serilog.json\" }}\n  {{ $mypath }}\n{{- end }}"},"kind":"ConfigMap","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"serilog-configmap","namespace":"monitoring"}}
```

some online post even says that the documentation may not be right. I copied the sample app from the website and that didnt work either. not sure, what i am doing wrong.
https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files/

Please note that if I simply copy the contents of my json below abc.json: |-, it works fine

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: abc-configmap
data:
  abc.json: |-
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether its a typo, but you are writing:
{{ .Files.Get "custom-dashboards/abc.json" | indent 4}}
and as for the structure - you wrote custom-dashboard.

Anyways, I am using: {{ tpl (.Files.Get $filename) . }}
and it works perfectly